# API responses adding "/" near of all " ' "

Tags: json, api, flask

When ı print my json_dump

```
{"accountNumber": 4176312, "currencyCode": "USD", "ownerName": "selman", "accountType": "individual", "balance": 0.0}
```

But when ı return

```
return make_response(jsonify(json_dump), status_code)
```

I see this

[image]

Why this ///// is coming ? How can ı solve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's wrong to have something like this. I am developing API for the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_dump` is, presumably, a string of JSON, (representing an object).

`jsonify` will convert that string to a JSON representation of that string which will cause any `"` in it to be escaped.

Send `json_dump` to the browser (where you want a JSON representation of an object).

Don't use `jsonify` on something that is already JSON (since a JSON representation of a JSON representation of an object isn't very useful).